# jQuery push menu elemnts reverse animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you tell me how can I do the reverse animation, because right now the animations just shows on click and on the second click when I close the push menu it just fades out.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".push-button").click(function () {
    $('.link-item-1').toggleClass('active-1');
    $('.link-item-2').toggleClass('active-2');
    $('.link-item-3').toggleClass('active-3');
    $('.link-item-4').toggleClass('active-4');
    $('.link-item-5').toggleClass('active-5');
  });
});
```

CSS (link-item):

```
#push-menu-inside .link-item {
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.link-item-1,
.link-item-2,
.link-item-3,
.link-item-4,
.link-item-5 {
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

CSS (active-open):

```
.link-item-2.active-2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
```

You can check the website here and its push-menu: vixxxademo.epizy.com

Comment: Seems like `#push-menu` is toggled too soon. Show the relevant code about it.

Comment: If you include a working example in a code snippet as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we might be able to help. Please see [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can check it on the website! vixxademo.epizy.com